# Delete path and its recursive child path in firebase cloud function

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to delete a document and all the collections that is inside the document from firestore. For that I'm using cloud function with node 8 as engine and it's actually deployed. But something isn't working as expected.

this is my route
/ *postsCollection* / *user* / *user_posts_collection* / *large documents*

So I want to **delete the user document** and all the things that contain inside that document => ***user_posts_collection*** and its documents

Node.js, Cloud Function

```
exports.deleteUserPostsDocument = functions
    .runWith({
        timeoutSeconds: 540,
        memory: '2GB'
    })
    .https.onCall(async(data, context) => {

        const path = data.path;

        await firebase_tools.firestore
            .delete(path, {
                project: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
                recursive: true,
                yes: true,
                token: functions.config().fb.token
            });

        return {
            path: path
        };
    });
```

Kotlin, call to function

```
val path = "/posts/user"
val data = hashMapOf("path" to path)

var success = false

functions
    .getHttpsCallable("deleteUserPostsDocument")
    .call(data)
    .continueWith {task ->
        success = task.isSuccessful
    }.await()

return success
```

The code is exactly the same as they show [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections), I just removed the code to access if you are just only admin. So there shouldn't be any problem with that.

I followed all the steps [they indicated](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli), with firebase login, firebase login:cli etc.. and I can see the function being deployed into my *firebase cloud functions*

Question: What am I missing?

Edit 1: Here's a screenshot that it's calling to the cloud function, but doesn't delete anything.
[image]

Comment: Note that env.GCLOUD_PROJECT is deprecated, use env.GCP_PROJECT instead. https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#runtime_environment_variables_set_automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to take a look at this [sample on github](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-node/tree/master/firestore/solution-deletes) and noticed a few things:

I had all the packages **except firebase-tools**, which is weird because I've wrote in command line 70 times *npm install -g firebase-tools* as the document indicates. So I decided to add it by myself so now **package.json contains the firebase-tools dependency**

```
"firebase-admin": "^9.1.1",
"firebase-functions": "^3.11.0",
"firebase-tools": "^8.9.0"
```

Then I rewrote the require of firebase_tools in index.js:

`const firebase_tools = require('firebase-tools')`

And just in case I set the token that you get by executing the command line: **firebase login:ci**

Set here `firebase functions:config:set fb.token="SET_TOKEN_HERE"`

Now execute the next command line: **firebase deploy --only functions** to update.

And finally works :)